# REST request returnig null PK from a @PathParam

Tags: java, angular, rest, http

I'm working on a project using a Java REST service and an Angular 6 client, but I'm getting an error on a PUT Request

> Request error message: HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
>   [Request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwf4m.png)

Here is the backend function:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}/edit")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public boolean editGroup(@PathParam("{id}") Long id, Object novo){
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) novo;
    String nome = map.get("nome");

    Grupo grupo = super.find(id);
    grupo.setNome(nome);

    if(Long.parseLong(map.get("idTrabalho")) > 0){
        Trabalho trabalho = em.find(Trabalho.class, Long.parseLong(map.get("idTrabalho")));
        grupo.setTrabalho(trabalho);
    }
    super.edit(grupo);
    return true;
}
```

Angular function:

```
editGrupo(grupo: Grupo): Observable<boolean> {
    const url = `${this.grupoUrl}/${grupo.id}/edit`;
    const temp = {
      'nome': grupo.nome,
      'idTrabalho': grupo.trabalho.id.toString(),
    };
    return this.http.put<boolean>(url, temp, this.httpOptions).pipe
    (catchError(this.handleError(`editGrupo ${grupo.id}`)));
}
```

The problems is that I'm using the same code in other Angular/Java objects and they don't get errors

Working example:

java:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}/edit")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public boolean createTrabalho(@PathParam("id") Long id, Object novo) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) novo;
    String nome = map.get("nome");      

    Trabalho trabalho = super.find(id);
    trabalho.setNome(nome);
    if(Long.parseLong(map.get("idProfessor")) > 0  && Long.parseLong(map.get("idDisciplina")) > 0){
        Professor professor = em.find(Professor.class, Long.parseLong(map.get("idProfessor")));
        Disciplina disciplina = em.find(Disciplina.class, Long.parseLong(map.get("idDisciplina")));
        trabalho.setProfessor(professor);
        trabalho.setDisciplina(disciplina);
    }        
    super.edit(trabalho);
    return true;
}
```

Angular:

```
editTrabalho(trabalho: Trabalho): Observable<boolean> {
    const url = `${this.trabalhoUrl}/${trabalho.id}/edit`;
    const temp = {
        'nome': trabalho.nome,
        'idProfessor': trabalho.professor.id.toString(),
        'idDisciplina': trabalho.disciplina.id.toString(),
    };
    return this.http.put<boolean>(url, temp, this.httpOptions).pipe(
           catchError(this.handleError(`editTrabalho ${trabalho.id}`)));
}
```

I can't find why it's happening only in this object, I also checked the HTTP Request and couldn't find any problem or difference between the one that gets an error and the one which works.

Angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.5
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.5
@angular/cli                      6.0.5
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.0
@schematics/angular               0.6.5
@schematics/update                0.6.5
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.6.0
```

Edit:

Glassfish stack trace:

```
Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB             
GrupoFacadeREST, method: public boolean br.com.x9.servicos.GrupoFacadeREST.editGroup(java.lang.Long,java.lang.Object)
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4600)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2108)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2078)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy217.editGroup(Unknown Source)
at br.com.x9.servicos.__EJB31_Generated__GrupoFacadeREST__Intf____Bean__.editGroup(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at br.com.x9.controller.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:54)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.findInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:878)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:822)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:688)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.find(EntityManagerWrapper.java:342)
at br.com.x9.servicos.AbstractFacade.find(AbstractFacade.java:38)
at br.com.x9.servicos.GrupoFacadeREST.editGroup(GrupoFacadeREST.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4820)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:824)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4792)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4780)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
... 62 more

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[br.com.x9.servicos.ApplicationConfig]: Servlet.service() for servlet br.com.x9.servicos.ApplicationConfig threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.findInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:878)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:822)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:688)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.find(EntityManagerWrapper.java:342)
at br.com.x9.servicos.AbstractFacade.find(AbstractFacade.java:38)
at br.com.x9.servicos.GrupoFacadeREST.editGroup(GrupoFacadeREST.java:83)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4820)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:824)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:823)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4792)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4780)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy217.editGroup(Unknown Source)
at br.com.x9.servicos.__EJB31_Generated__GrupoFacadeREST__Intf____Bean__.editGroup(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at br.com.x9.controller.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:54)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: please add error line or stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some curly brackets arround the @PathParam id, removed the brackets and the code worked.

Code with error:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}/edit")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public boolean editGroup(@PathParam("{id}") Long id, Object novo){
    // Code
}
```

Fixed code:

```
@PUT
@Path("{id}/edit")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public boolean editGroup(@PathParam("id") Long id, Object novo){
    // Code
}
```